# There are an error on addJavascriptInterface method about WebViewClassic

Tags: android

The class `WebViewClassic` throws a `NullPointerException` when it invokes `addJavascriptInterface` method on Android 4.3. I don't find the `NullPointerException` from the system source of android 4.3. `addJavascriptInterface` method

[image]

I think it should be a system bug. Help me please. thanks.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.addJavascriptInterface(WebViewClassic.java:4314)
at android.webkit.WebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebView.java:1533)
at com.browser.webview_checkmode.BrowserWebViewFactory$1.run(BrowserWebViewFactory.java:71)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5166)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

Comment: I can't find the result of this question on stackoverflow,please help me,thanks.

Comment: use WebView instead of WebViewClassic. Can you show us code where the error occured?

Comment: the codes run in a thread:`webView.addJavascriptInterface(new VideoBridge(context, webView),
                                VideoBridge.videoBridgeName);
                        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new GovInteraction(webView), GovInteraction
                                .GOV_INTERACTION_NAME);`